# Is there a regedit key in windows that blocks the running of exe files (by services)

Tags: windows, process, registry, exe, regedit

I have a Windows Service that runs an `exe` file and it is working fine under Win7 and Win8 Environments. But when I try the program in a Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2012 Environment, the service works but the exe file is not run. So I am wondering if there is a regedit key that blocks running of exe files when they are run from `Session 0` or something similar.

I have noticed that Windows 2012 by default blocks running interactive programs. But I have already allowed it by setting the following value to zero.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows
NoInteractiveServices
```

Answer (score 0):

When you install a Windows Service in Windows Server enviorment, you need to check Allow service to interact with desktop property in the service properties -> Log On. 
When this property is enabled, try to restart Interactive Services Detection service.

Comment: This option is only available when you Log On as a Local System Account and not when you are running the service as a specific user. In other instances of the exact same program that I have run on other operating systems, the program is run successfully.